# Too many open files issue in xcode 14.3.1 react native v0.63.3 app

Tags: react-native, xcode14, macos-ventura, watchman

How to fix too many open files issue on xcode 14.3.1. Below are env details and error message. Is react-native v0.63.3 compatible with ventura OS?

**Details:**

Mac OS:- ventura OS

Xcode version :- Version 14.3.1 (14E300c)

React native version:- "react": "16.13.1", "react-native": "0.63.3",

iphone:- iphone14, ios version 16.2

NodeJS:- v12.22.12

**Error Message:**
Error:
*EMFILE: too many open files, watch*
*Showing All Issues
Obfuscation SKIPPED [Development mode. Override with JSO_METRO_DEV=true environment variable]

```
             Welcome to React Native!
            Learn once, write anywhere
```

Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange
(internal/fs/watchers.js:168:28)

- [[ true != true ]]

the transform cache was reset.*